# Printing arrays of an array in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array `contacts[]` and inside this array are `contact` objects. Now the `contact` objects have another array `hashtags[]` which contain strings.

How do I get the hashtags to show using `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <tr ng-repeat="hashtag in contact.hashtags">
      <td>{{hashtag}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
      <tr ng-repeat="tag in contact.hashtags">
        <td ng-bind="tag"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

You can get index of inside ng-repeat with `$index` and parent ng-repeat using `$parent.$index`.

Or you can use

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(parentIndex, contact) in contacts">
      <tr ng-repeat="(childIndex, tag) in contact.hashtags">
        <td ng-bind="tag"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```